# What does Regenerating Techno-Organics cost for an 'Oid?

Tags: mekton

'Oids (MZP P. 93) mentions the following:

> ...and do not need to buy Techno-Organics, Internal Automation, Throught control or the Transformable Option of Disguise; the 'Oid effect covers all of these.

On the page with Techno-Orgamics (MZP P. 80) it gives three cost multiplyers, for Techno-Organics, Regenerating and Regenerating Techno-Organics. The last one is a mix of the previous one with no extra bonuses, but is cheaper than if you bought the two together.

If you wanted to give your 'Oid Regenerating Techno-Organics, what would you have to buy? Regenerating at its regular cost, RTO at its normal cost or at the discount of the cost mentioned for just Techno-Organics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the literal understanding of the book, you'd probably pay its regular price.

I would rule that you should pay less, though the question is "how much less?"

The Regenerating Techno-Organics package is priced about 10% cheaper than the sum of its parts, so you could add Regenerating to 'Oid, which already has Techno-Organics, for x0.225.

But one could also argue that RTO is priced at x0.67 vs Techno-Organics' x0.5, so you could add Regeneration to 'Oid for just x0.17.

The second variant looks more in line with the "sum all the multipliers" logic, so I'd use that.